# cant find jquery.js for rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

i have an error , when trying to use highcharts.

```
javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.2.min","rails","highcharts"
```

> "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.14/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.js
>   isn't in paths: C:/Users/Home/proj/lp/app/assets/images,
>   C:/Users/Home/proj/lp/app/assets/javascripts,..."

i am newbie. using rails 3.1.0
Dont know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.2.min","rails","highcharts"
```

Use this:

```
javascript_include_tag "application"
```

Then configure your js in application.js:

like so:

```
//= require jquery-1.4.2.min
//= require rails
//= require highcharts
```

Information regarding how to format your assets so that they are brought in the way you want them is located here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Answer (score 0):

Try just renaming your `app/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js` to `jquery.js`.  I think somewhere you're trying to include the file by just `jquery.js` and it's not finding it.  If you do this, make sure you change all references to `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` to point to just `jquery.js`